# query with time spent condition

Tags: mysql

My query

```
SELECT cookie_name, 
       SUBTIME( CURTIME( ), 
       min( time ) ) AS spent <='00:01:00', 
       date, sum( cookie_view ) AS views 
FROM cookie_table  
GROUP BY cookie_name, date 
    HAVING sum( cookie_view ) =1
```

it getting output

```
                  cookie_name      spent               date   views   
                  5gm7aXUvkbhh   00:25:44.000000     25/11/16    1
                  ZR7929L32Bq    00:28:30.000000     25/11/16    1
```

but i want like this count of views and spent < 1min ,2min and>3min in that query.

```
                       date      views    <1   <2   >3
                       25/11/16    2       0    0    2
```

Is it possible? here spent is > 3 so its show records count 2( 00:03:00<00:25:44.000000, 00:28:30.000000 )

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
SELECT `cookie_name`, 
       SUBTIME( CURTIME( ), 
       min( time ) ) AS `spent` <='00:01:00', 
       date, sum( `cookie_view` ) AS `views` ,
       sum(case `spent` when < '00:01:00' then 1 else 0 end) as `one`,
       sum(case `spent` when < '00:02:00' then 1 else 0 end) as `two`,
       sum(case `spent` when > '00:03:00' then 1 else 0 end) as `three`
FROM `cookie_table` 
GROUP BY `cookie_name`, `date` 
    HAVING sum( `cookie_view` ) =1
```

Comment: its getting error  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<='00:01:00', date, sum( cookie_view ) AS views , sum(case spent ' at line 3 @Steffen

Comment: Have you solved it in the meantime? Remove the ` then. My fault.